# What is the name of this functor that uses RankNTypes?

Tags: haskell, functor, higher-rank-types

During play around [objective](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/objective) package, I noticed following type has interesting property.

```
> {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
> data N f r = N { unN :: forall x. f x -> (x, r) }
```

It is a Functor.

```
> instance Functor (N f) where
>    fmap f (N nat) = N $ fmap (fmap f) nat
>          -- or,   = N $ \fx -> let { (x,a) = nat fx } in (x, f a)
```

After few hours of google/hoogle, I gave up finding any
existing module that includes this type.
*What is this type?* If it is well known, what is the name? Is this useful or ignored because useless?

This is not my 100% original creation, because N was derived from Object found in objective package.

```
> data Object f g = Object {
>     runObject :: forall x. f x -> g (x, Object f g)
>   }
```

`N f` is a Functor which yields `Object f Identity` when Fix is applied to.

---

Following is a fact about this type and why I thought it is interesting.

N converts Reader to Writer, vice versa.
(Here I used (=) symbol for isomorphism between types)

```
N ((->) e) r
 = forall x. (e -> x) -> (x, r)
 = (e, r)

N ((,) d) r
 = forall x. (d, x) -> (x, r)
 = d -> r
```

N converts Store comonad to State monad, but inverse is not true.

```
> data Store s a = Store s (s -> a)
> type State s a = s -> (s, a)

N (Store s) r
 = forall x. (s, (s -> x)) -> (x, r)
 = forall x. s -> (s -> x) -> (x, r)
 = s -> (s, r)
 = State s r

N (State s) r
 = forall x. (s -> (s, x)) -> (x, r)
 = forall x. (s -> s, s -> x) -> (x, r)
 = forall x. (s -> s) -> (s -> x) -> (x, r)
 = (s -> s) -> (s, r)  -- ???
```

N can't take Maybe.

```
N Maybe r
 = forall x. Maybe x -> (x, r)
 = forall x. (() -> (x, r), x -> (x, r))
 = Void     -- because (() -> (x, r)) can't be implemented
```

Following function may be fun. I couldn't do it's inverse.

```
> data Cofree f a = Cofree a (f (Cofree f a))
> data Free f a = Pure a | Wrap (f (Free f a))

> unfree :: Free (N f) r -> N (Cofree f) r
> unfree (Pure r) = N $ \(Cofree a _) -> (a, r)
> unfree (Wrap n_f) = N $
>   \(Cofree _ f) -> let (cofree', free') = unN n_f f
>                    in unN (unfree free') cofree'
```

Entire post is literate Haskell (.lhs).

Comment: I know no name for that, but write it as `(forall x. f x -> ((,) r) x)` and it becomes something that can be passed to `Control.Comonad.Cofree.hoistFree`.

Comment: @chi There's no `g` in `N`. It's setting `g ~ Identity` in `Object f g`. If you drop the uninteresting `Identity`s` from `forall x. f x -> Identity (x, Object f Identity)` you get `forall x. f x -> (x, Object f)`. If you replace the recursive occurrence of `Object f` with a new parameter `r` you get `forall x. f x -> (x, r)`, which is `N f r`. `Fix (N f)` puts the recursive occurrence back in where the `r` was.

Comment: This looks like [`Ran`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors/docs/Data-Profunctor-Ran.html#t:Ran), but mixing and matching profunctors and bifunctors. `forall x. f x -> x` is an index into `f`. The other part is a reader from the environment of `forall x. f x`, reading the structure of `f` but not its values.

Comment: @Gurkenglas and @Cirdec, thank you for the comments. `Ran` seems to be able to represent `N`, but it is not the way Ran was supposed to (use with profunctors, like `(->)`), but with bifunctors `(f x, a)` and `(x, b)`. Correct me if I misunderstanding, I haven't learned Category theory but few blog posts of someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call it a "handler" functor. `Object` used to be defined using the handler functor before I released objective.

Yeah, this functor is interesting -- `Cofree (Handler f)` has a public getter and `Free (Handler f)` is a [mortal object](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/objective-1.1.1/docs/Control-Object-Mortal.html). Maybe I should have shipped the handler functor...

Answer (score 1):

Although it is already answered, I found another answer to the question by myself.

Type `N` was the value-level representation of the type class `Pairing`, described in following articles.

[Free for DSLs, cofree for interpreters](http://dlaing.org/cofun/posts/free_and_cofree.html)

[Cofree Comonads and the Expression Problem](http://comonad.com/reader/2008/the-cofree-comonad-and-the-expression-problem/)
(Paring is called Dual here)

## Pairing and `N` are same things

The definition of Pairing is this.

```
> class Pairing f g where
>   pair :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> g b -> c
```

`f` and `N f` is Pairing.

```
> instance Pairing f (N f) where
>   pair k fa nb = uncurry k $ unN nb fa
```

`N` can be represented in terms of Pairing.

```
> data Counterpart f r = forall g. Pairing f g => Counterpart (g r)
>
> iso1 :: N f r -> Counterpart f r
> iso1 = Counterpart
>
> iso2 :: Counterpart f r -> N f r
> iso2 (Counterpart gr) = N $ \fx -> pair (,) fx gr
```

There is a Free-vs-Cofree instance, that corresponds to my `unfree`.
Other interesting instances are also defined in the articles.

```
> instance Pairing f g => Pairing (Free f) (Cofree g) where
>   pair = undefined -- see link above
```

## Extending Pairing to PairingM to Object

Former article [goes to](http://dlaing.org/cofun/posts/pairing_over_the_network.html) extending Pairing to do computation inside a Monad m.

```
> class PairingM f g m | f -> g, g -> f where
>   pairM :: (a -> b -> m r) -> f a -> g b -> m r
```

If we rewrite PairingM to a form similar to N, we get the Object again.

```
> -- Monad m => HandlerM' f m r ~ HandlerM f m r
> data HandlerM' f m r = forall g. PairingM f g m => HandlerM' (g r)
> data HandlerM f m r = HandleM { runHandlerM :: forall x. f x -> m (x, r) }
>
> -- Fix (HandlerM f m) ~ Object f m
> -- Free (HandlerM f m) ~ (mortal Object from f to m)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Applicative interface can be implemented in various ways, for example instead of liftA2 you can implement (**)

```hs
(**) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
(**) = liftA2 (,)
```

You can understand this as returning a datatype we will call Curried:

```hs
(**) :: Applicative f => f a -> (forall b. f b -> f (a, b))
     :: Applicative f => f a -> Curried f f a
     :: Applicative f => f   ~> Curried f f
```

We define [Curried](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2.5/docs/Data-Functor-Day-Curried.html) as such

```hs
type    Curried :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype Curried f g a = Curried (forall b. f b -> g (a, b))
```

In the kan-extensions package it is actually defined as:

```hs
type    Curried :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype Curried f g a = Curried (forall b. f (a -> b) -> g b)
```

which comes from the (<*>) operator

```hs
flip (<*>)
    :: Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
    :: Applicative f => f a -> (forall b. f (a -> b) -> f b)
    :: Applicative f => f a -> Curried f f a
    :: Applicative f => f   ~> Curried f f
```

So you can think of `N` as being `Curried f Identity`.

```hs
{-# Language DerivingVia #-}

type    N :: (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
newtype N f r = N (forall x. f x -> (r, x))
  deriving Functor
  via Curried f Identity
```

Curried, for the categorically minded, is right-adjoint to the Day convolution (Day f -| Curried f), so this is a natural isomorphism:

```hs
Day f g -> h
      <->
g -> Curried f h
```

The Day convolution is similarly defined, but contravariantly: so the quantification is existential.

```hs
liftA2
    :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> (f a -> f b -> f c)
    :: Applicative f => (exists a b. (a -> b -> c, f a, f b)) -> f c
    :: Applicative f => Day f f c -> f c
    :: Applicative f => Day f f   ~> f

type Day :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
data Day f g a where
  Day :: (a -> b -> c) -> (f a -> g b -> Day f g c)
```